# Deleting particular string from list irrespective of uppercase/lowercase using Python

Tags: python, list

I want to delete all desired items from the list. This is my code below:

```
filenameContainList = ["abc_001", "ZZ_ABC_dd_002", "abCXXyy_003", "PPP_004", "Fabc  FABC FabC abc"]
userInputForRemove = ["abc","ppp"]
updatedFileNameList = []

import re
for i in userInputForRemove:
    repat = "(.*){}(.*)".format(i)
    for j in filenameContainList:
        tmp = re.search(repat, j, re.IGNORECASE)
        if tmp:
            token = "".join(tmp.groups())
            updatedFileNameList.append(token)
print(updatedFileNameList)
```

My output looks like this :

```
['_001', 'ZZ__dd_002', 'XXyy_003', 'Fabc  FABC FabC ', '_004']
```

But I want output to look like this :

```
['_001', 'ZZ__dd_002', 'XXyy_003', 'F  F F ', '_004']
```

Can anyone let me know where I am making a mistake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this,

```
import re

replace_ = re.compile("|".join(userInputForRemove), flags=re.IGNORECASE)

print([replace_.sub("", x) for x in filenameContainList])
```

---

```
['_001', 'ZZ__dd_002', 'XXyy_003', 'F  F F ', '_004']
```